# how to append url with parameter in angular 2 type script?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a problem regarding appending url params dynamically in angular 2. The angular 1 uses $location.search to add query params in the url. How could i achieve the same in Angular 2 ?

```
//Api call to submit product details
submit_product() {
                let model = new AddProductModel(this.post_dict.name, this.post_dict.slug, 'N', 0, this.post_dict.display_sitewide, this.post_dict.display_in_party, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bundled')), 'N', parseInt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categories'))));
                this
                        .product
                        .addProduct(model)
                        .then(productObj => {
                                if (productObj) {
                                        localStorage.removeItem('categories');
                                        // Here i wish to set the object id as the URL parameter;
                                        this.successMessage = 'Product Information added Successfully';
                                        this.timeoutMethod(true);
                                }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                                this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
                                this.timeoutMethod(false);
                        })

        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated!! Thankss a tonnn.

Comment: `Use this._router.navigate(['/booking',{ id: 'keeping'}])` where `/booking` is path and `{id: 'keeping;}` is the id that you wish to pass

Comment: How is the code you provided even related to your question? I see no url there anywhere? And *url with parameter*, do you mean a http call or routing? :)

Comment: @Smit Thankss a tonnn it really helped!!!

Comment: Hope that helped @AbhijeetChakravorty I have added that as a answer, if you require any more help, let me know.

Comment: @Smit thankss a tonn will stay in touch :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.ts`

Use `this._router.navigate(['/booking',{ id: 'keeping'}])` where `/booking` is path and `{id: 'keeping;}`

In `.html`

Use `[routerLink]="['/booking',{ service: 'keeping'}]"` where `/booking` is path and `{id: 'keeping;}`

```
<a [routerLink]="['/booking',{ service: 'keeping'}]">Book</a>
```

Hope this helps.